# stored procedure for sending email with html table formatting issue

Tags: html, xml, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

On of the previous developers had a process that sent email alerts in the form of an html table in an email, this was done by triggering an stored procedure and passing the relevant parameters. This is a little outside my skills at the moment but im trying to get the same procedure to send an email for lateness. It works fine bar the formatting and layout. the query is -

```
SET @xml = CAST((   SELECT      td = '<td align = "Center">' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),EmployeeName) + '</td>'
                                , td = '<td align = "Center">' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),StartTime) + '</td>'
                                , td = '<td align = "Center">' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),Late) + '</td>'
                    FROM        #tempLateEmail  

                    FOR XML PATH('tr'),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'
                    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
```

The body output is :

```
SET @body = 
                  N'<style type="text/css">'
            + 'body {font-family: Arial;font-size:12px;} '
            + 'table{font-size:11px; border-collapse:collapse;table-layout: fixed} '
            + 'td{ border:1px solid black; padding:3px;} '
            + 'th{background-color:#F1F1F1;border:1px solid black; padding:3px;}'
            + 'h1{font-weight:bold; font-size:12pt}'
            + 'h2{font-weight:bold; font-size:10pt}'
        + '</style>'
        + '<body style="width:620px; margin:15px;">'
            + '<div style="margin:0 auto; width:300px">'
                + '<h1>Lateness Email on' + ' ' + convert(varchar, getdate(), 103) + '</h1>'
            + '</div>'
            + '<div style="float:left; width:250px">'
                + '<p>The following people appear to have been late today</p> '
            + '</div>'
            + '<div style="float:left; margin-left:20px; width:250px">'
                + '<div style="height:150px; overflow:auto">'
                + '<table width="250px">'
            + '<tr>'
            + '<th width = 100>Employee</th>'
            + '<th width =100>Expected Start Date</th>'
            + '<th width =100>Minutes Late</th>'
            + '</tr>'
                + @xml
                + '</table>'
                + '</div>'
            + '</div>'

            + '<div style="clear:both;"></div>'
        + '</body>' 

        SET @subject = 'Lateness Email for - ' + convert(varchar, getdate(), 103)
```

It then outputs them side by side instead of in a table. I understand why its doing it but I can not work out what to do about it. Hope i've provided enough info

Comment: put your + @xml in <tr>

Answer (score 0):

as per Rohit Tiwari's comment there was indeed a `<tr>` missing from the end of the top secion of code -

```
SET @xml = CAST((   SELECT      td = '<td align = "Center">' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),EmployeeName) + '</td>'
                                , td = '<td align = "Center">' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),StartTime) + '</td>'
                                , td = '<td align = "Center">' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),Late) + '</td>**<tr>** '
                    FROM        #tempLateEmail  

                    FOR XML PATH('tr'),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'
                    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
```

highlighted the update above.